# display output completely in GAP

Tags: gap

If GAP computes large output it will be shortenend by ( [...] ). How can I display the whole output?

Unfortunately I have not found an answer yet.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want `PrintTo`.

Answer (score 3):

GAP has several kinds of printing functions: Results returned from the command line are processed by `View' (which as you noted shortens large permutations -- this is to avoid filling up the screen with data one typically does not need to see explicitly).

If you call `Print' on your result, for example

```
g:=Image(RegularActionHomomorphism(MathieuGroup(11)));
Print(g.1);
```

you get the full gory output.

Comment: And the link to the manual section describing that is [here](http://gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap6.html#X8074A8387C9DB9A8)